# Customized checkbox does not show image when checked

Tags: php, javascript, css

```
body {
    font: 0.8em/21px arial,sans-serif;
}
/*checkbox declaration*/
.checkbox {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url('/karentest/images/selected.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
/* 
    Hide the original checkboxes
    (but still accessible)

    :not(#foo) > is a rule filter to block browsers
                 that don't support that selector from
                 applying rules they shouldn't     
*/

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] {

    /* Hide the input, but have it still be clickable */
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 19px;
}

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    margin: 0;
    display: none;    
    /* Left padding for image */
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;
    /* Make look clickable because they are */
    cursor: pointer;

    background: url('/karentest/images/select.png') left center no-repeat; 
}

/*
    Change from unchecked to checked graphic
*/

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
display: block;
background: url('/karentest/images/selected.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Here's the CSS Code of my project. What I want is to customize the checkbox and for it to display an image when it is not checked and another image when it is checked. But what happens is that the image is not displayed whenever it is checked. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried getting the images some other way, to make sure they are being served?

Comment: I tried changing and switching the unchecked and checked image. but only the image in the unchecked state is being displayed. I haven't tried getting them some other way...

Comment: I also got this javascript code. But still, it's not working (not displaying image in checked state).

Comment: try wget or a browser fetch on both images, without anything else, just to see if they are both actually being transmitted by the server.  If one of them turns up missing, then you know to correct the problem with the server first.  If you don't check this then you can do a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: var checkboxHeight = "25";

document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } </style>');

Comment: I can view both images. what else can I do to fix this problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the elements using the chrome or ff dev tools to make sure the styles are applying correctly.